# Is It Efficient and Scalable for a Neural Network to Rely on Weights that Require Database Interaction?

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, neural-network

I'm a high school senior interested in computer science and I have been programming for almost nine years now. I've recently become interested in machine learning and I have decided to implement a neural network. I haven't begun to code it yet and have been in the designing stage for  a while now. The objective of the program is to analyze a student's paper, along with some other information, and then predict what grade the student will receive, much like [PaperRater](https://www.paperrater.com). However, I plan to make it far more personal than [PaperRater](https://www.paperrater.com).

The program has four inputs, one is the student's paper, the second is the student's id (i.e, primary key), third is the teacher's id, and finally the course id. I am implementing this on a website where registered, verified users alone can submit their papers for grading. The contents of the paper are going to be weighed in relation to the relationship between the teacher and student and in relation to the course difficulty. The network adapts to the teacher's grading habits for certain classes, the relationship between the teacher and student (e.g., if a teacher dislikes a student you might expect to see a drop in the student's grades), and the course-level (e.g., a teacher shouldn't grade a freshman's paper as harshly as a senior's paper).

However, this approach poses some considerable problems. There is an inherent limit imposed, where the numbers of students, teachers and courses prove to be too much and everything blows up! That's because there is no magic number which can account for every combination of student, teacher and course.

So, I've concluded that each teacher, student, and course must have an individual (albeit arbitrary) weight associated with them, not present in the Neural Network itself. The teacher's weight would describe her grading difficulty, and the student's weight would describe her ability as a writer. The weight of the course would describe the difficulty of the course. Of course, as more and more data is aggregated, the weights should adapt to become more accurate representations.

I realize that there is a relation between teachers and students, teachers and courses, and students and courses; therefore, I plan to make three respective hidden layers which sum the weights of its inputs and apply an activation function. How could I store the weights associated with each teacher, student and course, though?

I have considered storing it in their respective tables, but I don't know how well that would scale (or for that matter, if it would work). I also considered storing it in a file and calling it like that, but I'm sure that would be even worse than storing it in a database.

So the main question I have is: is it (objectively) efficient, in terms of space and computational complexity, and scalable, to store and manage separate, individual weights for each possible element of certain inputs in a SQL database outside of the neural network, if there are a finite (not necessarily small) amount of possible choices for such inputs, and still receive a reasonable output?

Regardless, I would like an explanation as to how come. I believe it would be just fine, but I can't justify it myself and so I'm asking for help. Thanks in advance!

(P.S.: If you realize any problems with my approach not covered in the scope of this question, or have general advice, please include it as an addendum to your answer or please message me).

Comment: A couple of questions. How do you intend to use these weights? How will a given paper be preprocessed so it can be evaluated by the neural network?

Comment: @jorgenkg I plan to accept PDF, Word and OpenOffice files which will be converted to a certain format, likely XML. Then, I will check the grammar, punctuation, vocabulary, thesis, and in-line citations, giving each separate category a different score. If you're referring to the weights I'm asking about, then I will use the teacher, student and course weights to account for biases. For example, some teachers might be biased for or against students, or some teachers grade certain courses far differently from other courses. The weights should account for such instances.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the neural network? It sounds like the solution you've described doesn't need a neural network, but rather a simple regression? Nevertheless, if the software should be able to handle massive amounts of numbers, a database might be applicable. It is at least more efficient than reading a .txt file

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean now. The purpose is to find a correlation between grades and teachers, with respect to the student, the paper and the course. Of course, that's if there is any correlation at all. I think I can see how a regression tree might solve this, but my method of attacking the problem is as such: enter the inputs, call database for the weight of the teacher (T), course (C), and student (S); then, a hidden neuron will activate the multiplication of pairs of relationship, e.g. TC, CS, TS. Thus, it should account for cases like bias, hard or easy courses, etc.